# JSONSerializer can't parse null values inside object

Tags: java, json, jpa

I'm using net.sf.json inorder to create a json string from a list of objects.

This is My code:

```
List<MyObject> results = em.createNamedQuery("MyObject.findAll").getResultList(); 
String gridRecords = JSONSerializer.toJSON(results).toString();
```

My problem is when one of the fields inside the object is null (even if the field is allowed to be null). I get this exception:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

am I doing somthing wrong? How can I get a json object from a list of objects when some fields inside these objects will be null?

Thank's In Advance.